# Run .sh on mac remotely from server

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access, psexec

Not sure how clear the title is, but basically I've created a program for Windows which my company can use to build games remotely from their desktops. Currently the Windows aspect works without a hitch, but I'm struggling to get our Mac to build.

We use `psexec` for the Windows side, and I tried to use it for Mac as well (just hoping), to be stuck with an `Invalid Handle` error.

The way the program works is the user selects from their system tray what they want to build, we have two options that require the Mac, both of those currently are the only ones that don't work.

We do have the ability to remotely access the Mac as well, but we're looking to mostly automate the process so that literally anyone (even the non-technically savvy) can click two buttons and create a build.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable given only the background in the question. You're mentioning `ssh` in the tags -- are you actually trying to use it in your implementation? *How*? How does it fail? Can you show representitive code, and exact error messages? Etc.

Comment: The security model you have for your company also matters. If you're doing things the Right Way, you'll actually be having the individual user account triggering the build authenticate to the system running the build machine, *or* locking down the access mechanism sufficient that it can't do anything *other than* run a build with code from a trusted source. All these details are things that need to be discussed in coming up with a recommendation, but aren't covered in the question as-given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I'm pretty new to this side of programming, so pardon my ignorance. I put ssh in because I saw some mentions of ssh being a potential solution but I didn't quite understand. Primarily where it is failing at the moment is using psexec, it does not allow me to gain access to the Mac, I constantly get the `Invalid Handle` error, despite putting in the information I know is for sure correct.

Comment: `psexec` is not expected to work with any target platform other than Windows, so that's expected there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I suppose what I'm looking for then is an alternative that either a) works with both Windows and Mac or b) works with mac alone, seems fairly obvious that A would be the optimal solution, but I don't know a huge amount about this stuff

Comment: ssh *is* the best-practice solution for this; it *can* work on Windows if you set it up appropriately -- see ie. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC150. However, walking you through that setup is beyond what's generally considered reasonable question scope here.

Comment: now, what's *tricky* (as in, you'll want to delegate it to a professional sysadmin) is to get a Mac to participate in your Active Directory domain to the point of validating a Kerberos ticket from your Windows client over SSH via GSSAPI. If you want the credentials of your currently-logged-in user to be used to kick off the build, though, that's what you're liable to want. Or you can do the easier thing and have RSA keys for your users, or the insecure thing and have a *shared* RSA key, or many alternatives between.

Comment: ...if y'all are using GitHub (Enterprise or otherwise), you're presumably using OpenSSH key-based authentication already, so that's the easiest thing to apply here. But, again, fact-intensive investigation, beyond the scope of a reasonable StackOverflow question.

Comment: Yikes okay, far more complicated than I think any of us had anticipated. Thanks a lot for your help, we don't have a dedicated system admin (we're a small team of 15), so we'll just stick to how we currently have it and maybe figure it out at a later time. Thanks again!

Comment: If this is for your build server, you might consider something like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) -- that way you have a nice, clean, platform-independent HTTP API interface. I've built much fancier systems for places where we had more stringent security requirements (like doing heavily sandboxed builds of code from untrusted sources), but it sounds like you're not in that kind of position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149183/discussion-between-andrew-b-and-charles-duffy).